# Make Mac act as Bluetooth headset for PS4

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I would love to route my PS4's audio through my macbook pro. Is there any way to make my macbook pro pretend to be a headset for the PS4?

Comment: I'd love to see someone use a macbook as a bluetooth headset. I'm all for this idea... but an actual ps4 compatible headset might be a way better choice.

Comment: Have one, was just having one earbud of one and one earbud of the other and thinking "This is terrible, I should be able to have the PS4 stream to the laptop and hear both at the same time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use your Mac as a *speaker* for other Apple devices (e.g. using software to turn your Mac into an Airplay receiver). However, there's no *current* way to turn it into a Bluetooth speaker for devices such as a PS4.

I suspect this would be possible in theory, however there probably just isn't the demand. The reason why software exists to turn your Mac into a receiver for other Apple devices is that there is a lot of demand for this, especially from iOS users, so various developers have answered the call over the years.

Comment: Oh well... maybe I'll have free time in the future and make something that does this lol, but thanks for the response!^^